# Angular 5 - Caching Service Does not work with router linking

Tags: angular

I have the following caching service. DataService merely uses HttpClient module to return JSON data.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CategoryService extends DataService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    super(environment.baseUrl + "category", http);
}

private cache$: Observable<Category>;

public get categories() {
  if (!this.cache$) {     
   this.cache$ = this.requestCategories().pipe(
     shareReplay(10) 
   );
 }

 return this.cache$;
}

private requestCategories(): Observable<Category> {
  return this.getAll(); // this is implemented in DataService
}
```

I have a component which puts the categories returned in a dropdown list. I use the  selector to add this to a web page. This works as expected. The first time thru the service, there is no cached data, so it is fetched and stored, and the next time the cache is used.

I call the get property in the service from the category component thusly:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories$ = this.categoryService.categories;
  }
```

But aye, here's the rub: if I route to this component, say from a navigation bar, the service ALWAYS goes back to get new data. I.e., it is never cached. Here is the HTML for the router link:

```
 <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/category">Category</a>
```

Bottom line, Conan, why does the service always go back to get new data, rather than use the cache?

Happy Thanksgiving!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is with using `shareReplay()` operator. Thing is that when no subscriptions are left, the 'cached' data is flushed.

This is different with `publishReplay(1).refCount()` where the cache is kept even when the last subscriber unsubscribes.

This article describes it in detail:
https://ncjamieson.com/how-to-use-refcount/

The relevant section is **What does shareReplay do**

So, first try using `publishReplay(1).refCount()`. If this doesn't help, then you might want to save the data in the `localStorage`. Obviously, if you refresh the page all the in-memory cache will be gone anyway.